# Restore Bootloader in Windows XP using ERD Commander

Tags: windows-xp, boot, bootloader, erd

I need to restore a **boot loader** on my laptop. The problem is that Recovery utility from Windows XP install CD ask for **Administrator password**. I changed my Administrator password using **ERD Commander**. But it doesn't help me. I don't know why. My Administrator password(which I was change using ERD Commander) doesn't match in recovery utility.

So is there another way, how I can restore boot loader on my laptop? Can I restore loader using ERD Commander?

Thanks!

Comment: What are the symptoms you're experiencing? `bootmgr is missing` or similar?

Comment: @DanielB, `error: no such partition` and then I have `grub` command line. Before I had 2 partitions with Ubuntu and Windows. Yesterday I deleted partition with Ubuntu. Because I need to return this laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [`BOOTICE`](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Boot-Manager-Disk/Bootice.shtml) for these tasks. It's specifically intended to manage boot sectors and can install a number of stock ones including XP's. And it can be run from ERD.

Answer (score -1):

Windows XP is out of support, I would look at installing Linux/Windows7:

> http://www.pcworld.com/article/2107641/3-easy-linux-alternatives-for-windows-xp-refugees-who-dont-want-a-new-pc.html

If you really want XP back ERD may help. Use fixboot and fixmbr from the command line when booted from ERD.

Comment: This not a answer for my question. And this is not my laptop. All I need is to restore loader, before I give this laptop back. ERD command line haven't `fixboot` and `fixmbr` commands

Comment: Yes fixboot will do just that.

Comment: Sorry it's been a while since I've used ERD. Use the windows installation disk:
> http://www.mysolutions.it/reinstall-windows-xp-bootloader/

Comment: thanks, but as I wrote, rescue utility ask for Administrator password. I type my Administrator password, but I have also error that password is incorrect.

Comment: You could try this tool to reset the password: http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/

Comment: Thanks. But I wrote that I tried to reset my password and it's didn't help.

Comment: Maybe ERD password reset doesn't work? Are you sure you are resetting the password for the Administrator rather than the normal user

Comment: Yes. I'm sure.  It was only one user. Administrator.